# Conditional formatting to show date task completed is in/out of target with icons

Tags: conditional-formatting

apologies for asking a basic question.

If cell A2 contains the dates a task should be completed by, and cell B2 contains the actual date completed.

Can the icons be used to show a green tick next to the date (in B2) if it is = or < A2 or a Red Cross if it's > than A2?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

IMO not exactly a 'basic' Q. One solution, that does not use icon sets but attempts to mimic them, is to place in C1 and copy down to suit:

```
=IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<A1),CHAR(252),IF(A1<>"",CHAR(251),""))
```

then clear any existing CF, select ColumnC, choose Windings as font and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=C1=CHAR(251)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select red font <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.